# Client rectangle coordinates on screen

Tags: c++, winapi, plugins, browser

How can I get coordinates of a window's client area relative to screen?

I thought about using `GetClientRect` and `ClientToScreen`. Also, in a browser window what is `ClientRect`? Only rectangle with `HTML` document shown in it, or it includes browser bars and pop-up menus, that can possibly shrink dimension for `HTML` doc?

I've tried this:

```
HWND hWnd;
RECT rc;
if (GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc)) // get client coords 
{
    MapWindowPoints(hWnd, NULL, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc), 2); // converts rect rc points
    return rc.top;
}
```

But the sad thing is that browser's client rectangle includes all those pop-up browser menus and bars, therefore can't be used to detect accurate coordinates of browsers HTML document space. If anyone got suggestions how it can be done, will try it gladly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the `ClientToScreen` function:

```
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc); // get client coords
ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.left)); // convert top-left
ClientToScreen(hWnd, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc.right)); // convert bottom-right
```

What is the "client" rectangle in a browser depends on the browser implementation. You can use Spy++ to discover this for yourself.

Comment: Note that returns an invalid rectangle on RTL systems. Better is to use `MapWindowPoints` with a length of 2.

Comment: Stack around the variable `rc` was corrupted, seems you are right, will try `MapWindowPoints` now

Comment: I don't know what an RTL system is, but would declaring and using a separate POINT struct instead of a cast fix that issue?  That seems to work fine for me and my purposes.

Comment: @AbePralle: RTL is short for [right-to-left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left). It refers to text layouts, that are written from right to left, such as Arabic script. Using a separate `POINT` structure doesn't produce a valid rectangle.

Comment: why do you call the `ClientToScreen` two times, one for left and one for right?

Comment: @Ivanzinho `ClientToScreen` works on a `POINT` (x,y) and a rectangle consists of two POINTs (top-left, bottom-right). But better to use the `MapWindowPoints` function as suggested by Raymond Chen.

Comment: @JonathanPotter is this not an ugly design? `ClientToScreen` would have returned a `POINT` instead of replacing the input argument with the output result. It's hard to wrap the idea of how it works this way, are they saving some CPU cycles or RAM to chose that unnatural design?

Comment: @Ivanzinho This API would probably date back to the mid-1980s. C didn't support returning structs then and I'm guessing the API was designed around that limitation.

Answer (score 4):

To translate a window's client rectangle to screen coordinates, call the [MapWindowPoints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145046.aspx) function. It implements special handling to always return a valid `RECT`, even when used in scenarios that involve windows with [right-to-left layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599.aspx#layout_mirroring):

> If *hWndFrom* or *hWndTo* (or both) are mirrored windows (that is, have `WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL` extended style) and precisely two points are passed in *lpPoints*, `MapWindowPoints` will interpret those two points as a [`RECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162897.aspx) and possibly automatically swap the left and right fields of that rectangle to ensure that left is not greater than right.

Calling [ClientToScreen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183434.aspx) on both points in contrast fails to account for RTL layouts, and can produce an invalid `RECT`. It fails to adhere to one of the [rectangle coordinate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162900.aspx) invariants:

> The coordinate value of a rectangle's right side must be greater than that of its left side. Likewise, the coordinate value of the bottom must be greater than that of the top.

A reliable function to return a window's client rectangle in screen coordinates would look like this:

```
RECT client_rect_in_screen_space(HWND const hWnd) {
    RECT rc{ 0 };
    if (!::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc)) {
        auto const err_val{ ::GetLastError() };
        throw std::system_error(err_val, std::system_category());
    }

    ::SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);
    if(::MapWindowPoints(hWnd, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<POINT*>(&rc), 2) == 0) {
        auto const err_val{ ::GetLastError() };
        if (err_val != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::system_error(err_val, std::system_category());
        }
    }

    return rc;
}
```

---

The question update asks for a different, unrelated issue. There is no API built into the system, that allows you to query a web browser's display area for its HTML content. The most promising solution would be to employ [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). The question, however, is too broad to provide a more detailed answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by [`Raymond Chen`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen), the preferred way of doing this should be something like the following:

```
inline POINT get_client_window_position(const HWND window_handle)
{
    RECT rectangle;

    GetClientRect(window_handle, static_cast<LPRECT>(&rectangle));
    MapWindowPoints(window_handle, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<LPPOINT>(& rectangle), 2);

    const POINT coordinates = {rectangle.left, rectangle.top};

    return coordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
POINT origin;
origin.x = 0;
origin.y = 0;
ClientToScreen(hWnd, &origin);
```

Now `origin` is, in screen coords, the top left corner of the client area.

To convert (x,y) from client-area coords to screen coords, add `origin`.
To do the reverse, subtract.

Comment: As pointed by Mr. Raymond Chen, this snippet causing problem on RTL systems, so please dont use this.

Comment: If RTL means right to left, ScreenToClient can have problems (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952(v=vs.85).aspx) but the docs for ClientToScreen don't mention this.