# How to get the client window position using the WinApi?

Tags: c++, winapi

With the following code, I am able to get the `RECT` of the client area of a window:

```
RECT pos;
GetClientRect(handle, &pos);
```

However, the `left` and `top` members are always `0`. This only returns information about the width and height of the client area of the window.  I am looking for the coordinates of the client area on the screen, not just its size.

Using `GetWindowRect()` does not work, because it returns the window coordinates and not the client area. I want the `(left, top)` point to here:

[image]

But instead it points here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MSDN example:

```
RECT rMyRect;

GetClientRect(hwnd, (LPRECT)&rMyRect);
ClientToScreen(hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect.left);
ClientToScreen(hwnd, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect.right);
```

Comment: Which [returns an invalid rectangle on RTL systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734528/client-rectangle-coordinates-on-screen#comment22378286_15734569), as explained in a comment. Plus, when quoting, do provide attribution. *"The MSDN example"* is hardly sufficient.

Comment: Consider using [`MapWindowPoints()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046.aspx) instead. You can pass it a `RECT` and it will translate all 4 values at one time, as well as handle RTL translations: `MapWindowPoints(hwnd, NULL, (LPPOINT)&rMyRect, 2);`